# Returning particular output from Python function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose, in MATLAB, I have the following function:

```
function [sums, diff, prod] = myFun(a, b)  
    sums = a + b;
    diff = a - b;
    prod = a * b;
end
```

If I just wanted to return, say `diff`, I'd type in the console `[~, diff, ~] = myFun(6, 2)` and it returns `4`.

Now, if I write a similar thing in Python 3.10 (for purposes of this question, I'm using the Spyder IDE):

```
def myFun(a, b):
    sums = a + b
    diff = a - b
    prod = a * b
    return sums, diff, prod
```

I can type `sum, diff, prod = myFun(5, 3)` and I get the results stored in the workspace. If I only want the output `prod` from this function, is there a way to do this in a way similar to MATLAB? If not, how would I achieve this?

I would prefer to not store all outputs of the function in a tuple and access a desired element later, but to achieve something as slick as the MATLAB usage for a placeholder output.

Comment: prod = myFun(3, 5).  Then prod[-1] will give you the last value

Comment: @Maxwell D. Dorilea: That would return a tuple with all three values - wouldn't it?

Comment: The convention is to use `_` for unused results, e.g. `_, _, prod = myFun(5, 3)`. It's just a convention, `_` is a perfectly legal variable name.

Comment: @Vineet, It will return a tuple. So prod[-1] will give you the last value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns a tuple containing all three values.

You can unpack that tuple in a number of ways that might meet your requirements:

```
_, _, prod = myFun(3, 4)
print (prod)
# result: 12
```

Or you could just extract the third item in the tuple:

```
prod = myFun(3, 4)[2]
print (prod)
# result: 12
```

Using `_, diff, _ =`  doesn't really do anything different from `sums, diff, prod =`, you're still taking the three values in the tuple and assigning them to three variable names - it just so happens that one of those variable names is an underscore `_`, and you reuse it, so if you try to return the value of `_` afterwards - it'll return the value that was assigned to it last.

Just for fun you *could* take a fairly heavy handed approach to making accessing individual results more convenient by using something like `namedtuple`:

```
def myFun(a, b):
    from collections import namedtuple
    result = namedtuple('myFun_return', ['sums', 'diff', 'prod'])
    result.sums = a + b
    result.diff = a - b
    result.prod = a * b
    
    return result

prod = myFun(3, 4).prod
print (prod)
#result: 12
```

`result` in this context, would be a namedtuple, and you could access its three attributes - `sums`, `diff`, and `prod` by simply calling them on the result, without having to remember the order or anything. But like I said, that *is* a fairly hefty approach to something so minor...

Resources:
https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-unpacking-tuple/
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples_unpack.asp

Comment: You know, I totally forgot I could use `_` as a placeholder. My searches didn't come across those pages (and I'm still not used to a lot of the Pythonic jargon).